# Exclusive options with required arguments

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I am writing a code which has a main switch case create/start/stop.. which has varying number of arguments as input. I am trying to add commons cli to provide all arguments with correct tags.

I am trying to achieve either of below >

*-o start -p new -t abc*

*-o stop -p old -t abc*

*-o cancel -p old -t abc*

*-o create -p new -s zyx -t abc -g 1,23,23 -c "this is a comment"*

*-o comp -n 23 -m 1*

or

*-start -p new -t abc*

*-stop -p old -t abc*

*-cancel -p old -t abc*

*-create -p new -s zyx -t abc -g 1,23,23 -c "this is a comment"*

*-comp -n 23 -m 1*

using below code, i got to the point where start/stop/create are exclusive.. but i am not able make other options as required for start/stop..

```
 Option o = new Option("create", false, "Create new process");
 Option s = new Option("start", false, "Start created process");
 Option st = new Option("stop", false, "Stop running process");


 OptionGroup optionGroup = new OptionGroup( );    
 optionGroup.addOption(o);  
 optionGroup.addOption(s);
 optionGroup.addOption(st);
 optionGroup.setRequired(true);
 options.addOptionGroup( optionGroup );


 CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
 HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();


 try {
     cmd = parser.parse(options, args);

     if (cmd.hasOption("create"))
     {
         System.out.println("create selected");

     }

 } catch (ParseException e) {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     formatter.printHelp("Test_jar", options);

     System.exit(1);
 }
```

Comment: I fear commons-cli does not support this, so you would have to do checks after parsing.

Comment: Which lib can i try to get this implemented? i have spent over 2 days to figure this out with no luck..